# How to maintain 1000 blocking TCP connections in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp

The reason I need this is because I need to poll data from 1000 devices that have GPRS modem connected to them and client protocol implementation for this devices
has blocking API e.g.:

```
<data> = protocol.get_<some_data>(stream)
```

All get methods are blocking: they can only return data or raise exception. Stream is a TCP-socket connection that was established from GPRS modem to our app. Protocol is implemented in python. Protocol complexity is hard to describe there are about 100 different types of devices that have specific features and get methods are aware of this so protocol implementation is extremely complex to port it for example to go or erlang (I will ask such amount of money for this that my boss will cry). So the question can sound like how to maintain 1000 threads in python. I know that this amount if far beyond the python possibilities not only because of GIL (I use CPython at the moment) but also because OS will feel that third world war has began (I planned to pull all this on one server machine).

Comment: How frequently do you need to poll for data?  Can you modify the original socket code to be non-blocking?  And why wouldn't you just re-establish the TCP connection on each poll?

Comment: Frequency can range from 1 time per day to every 5 seconds. Connection must be persistent not because GPRS modems will feel lonely, but because there is a schedule of polling which is configured on the server and I cannot connect from server side to them. To make API non blocking I need to rewrite all this protocol implementation because it just written entirely in this manner and to switch to async solution is very hard, no extremly hard sound more precise.

Comment: The right solution is separate out the socket code from the device protocol code.  That is, the code that generates and parses protocol messages is completely separate from the socket code.  That would enable you to switch between blocking and non-blocking sockets.  (It would also enable you to unit test your protocol without a network connection, but I digress).  But that's probably not the answer you are looking for.

Comment: But I would think you'd have to handle failed TCP connections anyway and have reconnect logic.  So why not just have each connection get re-established on each polling interval?

Comment: @selbie Polling interval is unpredictable. And GPRS modems have dynamic IPs so I just don't know where they are, but they know where the server is so if they feel that connection is in heaven they reconnect to my-server.com. To make connection persistent this GPRS modems (which have Java ME on board) send heartbeats to the server every 20-30 seconds.

Comment: Can you use select.epoll()? If your are writing the server application from scratch then you can use a single thread service using epoll. Here you have a nice example http://scotdoyle.com/python-epoll-howto.html

Comment: Nop, epoll, like select and other similar stuff is good when all your code don't block for long time in my case it will block from 2 to 10 minutes so I need separate threads that can wait for response since all these threads need to work in parallel which is not the case with technique that you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you absolutely must use only blocking I/O (e.g. because you have an existing codebase that would be too expensive to rewrite to use non-blocking I/O), the easiest thing to do would be to simply spawn 1000 threads.  Most OS's can handle that many threads (albeit not necessarily all that efficiently), and the GIL will not be a problem because a thread that is blocked waiting for I/O does not hold the GIL.  (GIL is a problem only when you are trying to get a speedup by parallelizing CPU-bound computations; and it sound like all of your threads will be I/O-bound)

If you find that a process with 1000 threads is in fact too many threads for your OS of choice too handle acceptably, you could always break up the threads into multiple processes (e.g. 10 processes with 100 threads each, or whatever other ratio you find works best).  Then if the problem turns out to be a global-thread-limit problem (e.g. 1000 threads is too many, regardless of how many processes you spread them out over), then next thing you could do is spread them across multiple computers (e.g. 10 computers running 100 threads each).

These are all kind of ugly solutions, though; the real solution would be to rewrite the program to use non-blocking I/O so that each thread could handle a (potentially large) number of sockets concurrently.  If you haven't already read it, you might want to read the [C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) article on the subject of supporting many concurrent TCP connections well.

Comment: I'm aware of most approaches described in that article and must admit that threading approach is not ugly it is rather much simpler and more natural then event based approaches. But it has limitations - OS threads are very heavy. Python uses OS and this makes it pretty limited for my task.

Comment: Why do you think your OS can't handle 1000 threads?  On the contrary, I'm fairly sure it can.  These days, 1000 is not very many threads.  Systems have gotten faster, scaled up their memory, and on most OS, threads have gotten cheaper.  Have you measured the performance of using your blocking library to monitor 1000 threads?  If so, what were your results and how do they fall short of your desires?  If not, what's the basis for your statements that such a solution is not feasible?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone You're right, I should try it first this way. My opinion was based on my previous experience (Windows XP 32 bit, C++, native theads, long time ago). Where 200 threads basically killed the system. I google a bit and current versions of windows os family should be one order better. At last I should give it a try and if I see that I can cook eggs on my CPU then I'll search for another solution. Yes, my boss wants windows(

Comment: I'will leave this thread open and I'll paste my results here when I'll implement a working prototype of this system